# What is the name of the field or class of algorithms to map pairwise distances into a 2d space?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a triangular matrix of pairwise distances between N objects like below.

Can someone point me to the field(s) in ML (unsupervised learning) that will map this matrix of pairwise distances into a 2d space for visualization?

```
array([[    0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       [ 7186.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       [ 8291.,  8402.,     0.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       [ 8294.,  8396.,  5017.,     0.,     0.,     0.],
       [ 8173.,  8331.,  5345.,  4790.,     0.,     0.],
       [ 7738.,  7616.,  8795.,  8824.,  8682.,     0.]])
```

An intuitive way of saying this is to imagine these were people and the metric was "friendship". How would I find the cliques amongst the people?

Comment: I guess you want to use one of clustering algorithms...

Comment: Or manifold-learning / low-rank embedding.

Answer (score 2):

There is a field, "Graph Drawing", defined ([on Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_drawing)) as:

> Graph drawing is an area of mathematics and computer science combining
>   methods from geometric graph theory and information visualization to
>   derive two-dimensional depictions of graphs arising from applications
>   such as social network analysis, cartography, linguistics, and
>   bioinformatics.

There is a specific problem called "[Multi-Dimensional Scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)" that tries to find 2D coordinates whose distances match a given distance matrix.  Neat fact, you don't have to solve this as an optimization, you can directly and quickly compute the optimal solution based on eigenvectors of your distance matrix.

... and like MaxU said in an earlier answer, the question of finding clique suggests a clustering algorithm might be most relevant.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no different field devoted to the problem. Closest `"friendship"` will be to the manifold learning.

But there are techniques dispersed all over to visualize high dimensional data.below are few things which work in most cases.

- [TSNE](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html)
- I have seen [PCA](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) being used for the task using the dimensionality reduction
- Extension of PCA, Kernel PCA which work surprisingly better than PCA, of course this is domain specific

Moreover, I would suggest if visualization is the purpose, then you are not restricted till `2D`, by all means you can use `3D`

If this is something you are doing for the better understanding of data, and this is not part of the deployment kind of a stuff, I would suggest not delving a lot into it.Sometimes visualization is not appealing, but results make sense, at other times results do not make sense and visualization also does not give a clue of why. Also, if the premise is true, then finding distances between the vectors and plotting them also works.